# Files take longer to upload when running multiple Java apps to upload to Azure blob storage from a queue?

Tags: java, azure, file

I have a use-case where I need to send files on a queue to azure blob storage in Java. The files will need to be uploaded concurrently. Was wondering whether someone could help with the direction I am taking.

1. I have 4 java uploader apps (JARs) running that are listening on the queue and simply upload the file.
2. I am able to get my specific items from the queue so that the 4 uploader apps can upload files based on size. Each instance works with its own size group.0-10MB, 11MB to 30MB and so on.
3. I wrote the following from examples to upload a file.

   ```
       BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
               .endpoint(storageAccountUrl)
               .sasToken(sasToken)
               .buildClient();

       BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient =     blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(container);

       BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(targetFileName);

       blobClient.uploadFromFile(fullFileName);
   ```
4. The apps just gets the files from the queue and send it.

What I am observing is the 4 independent "Java uploader apps" running listening on the queue, they start taking longer to upload files to Azure storage. In order of number of Java apps running!

For example a 9MB file takes 7 seconds to upload one running on only one uploader app. When I am running 4 uploader apps, this same file takes about 27 seconds.

Is there anything I need to bear in mind when doing this?

Comment: That's exactly what you'd expect if the total upload rate is limited by the network connection between you and azure, or by the CPU on the machine the upload tasks are running on (unlikely)

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies ! I will try running these from different machines/locations and see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: I setup the application instances to run on different machines and did the uploads again. It did make a difference as you said and the uploads were a lot better! I want to mark your comment as the answer since it was the direction I was looking for @tgdavies thanks!